# How can i redirect my Blog to a Subdomain?

Tags: multisite, blog

I have a website and a blog say domain.com, now i want to keep the website as it is at domain.com and move just the blog to blog.domain.com using the same wordpress theme.
How can i do that?

Comment: Use a filter on the options for home & siteurl?

Comment: hi @janh
Can you please elaborate on what are you proposing

Comment: You do want to use the same installation, right? The simplest way, imho, would be to use [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) on [option_$name](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/option_(option_name)), namely `option_siteurl` and `option_home`, and set them to blog.domain.com when that's the hostname provided. You will probably need some logic for the permalinks, but they can be done with filters as well.